# Unable to locate a link using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate a link on a page using the xpath. When I use the Inspect Element command, the page source for the object is as follows:

```
<a id="TreeView1_LinkButtonMore" href="javascript:__doPostBack('TreeView1$LinkButtonMore','')">
    See more
</a>
```

My Selenium Code is as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='TreeView1_LinkButtonMore')")).Click();
```

Error I get is as follows:

The given selector `//*[@id='TreeView1_LinkButtonMore')` is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='TreeView1_LinkButtonMore')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i have notice `[` not ending in the XPath query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='TreeView1_LinkButtonMore']")).Click();
```

However, it might be worth pointing out that the shortcut for this exact same thing is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("TreeView1_LinkButtonMore")).Click();
```

Comment: Just noticed that this is a C# question. I'm a Java guy, so I am not absolutely certain of the capitalization in my edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your xpath. The closing should be square bracket not the curve bracket
Syntax: //tag-name[@attribute='value']

Try this:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='TreeView1_LinkButtonMore']")).Click();